# convert textbox data into integer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, textbox, typecasting-operator

I am trying to enter the value in textbox & i want to converted to integer .I am using VBA 2013.

I tried multiple way but i am getting expection all time

**Rated_current = CInt(Int(TextBox_RatedCurrent.Text))**

**Rated_current = CInt(TextBox_RatedCurrent.Text)**

**Rated_current = Convert.toInt32(TextBox_RatedCurrent.Text)**

```
Private Sub TextBox_Bmax_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_Bmax.TextChanged

    Rated_current = CInt(Int(TextBox_RatedCurrent.Text))
    Mod_current = TextBox_RatedCurrent.Text * TextBox_TotalDrate.Text
    Calculated_TempRise.Text = CInt(Max_temp / ((Log10(Mod_current) / Log10(Rated_current)) * 1.64))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Try This in V2013 c#**

```
int Rated_current;
bool check = int.tryParse(TextBox_RatedCurrent.Text,out Rated_current);
if(!check)
{

//Incoming value is wrong

}
```